# Logarithmic equations and solving for the unknown variable

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is e^x*e^(x+1)=e^2 ? The e is the natural number 2.718... not the variable e. My teacher doesn't give a lot of notes so I am not sure if I multiply the two exponents on the left side, being x*(x+1), or if i add them.

Answer (score 1):

$$e^x\times e^{x+1}=e^{x+x+1}=e^{2x+1}$$
If $e^x\times e^{x+1}=e^2$, then, by the above,
$$2x+1=2\\
\implies \boxed{x=\dfrac{1}{2}=0.5}$$

Comment: @IlaIsabelle Sure!